# RavenDbMessageBus for SignalR

Tags: ravendb, signalr, web-farm

Sooner or later I will need to run multiple SignalR hosts. I know what a MessageBus is and i know that there is a MessageBus for SQL Server and Redis.
Implementing one for RavenDB looks doable.

The question is: Since the application already uses RavenDB for storing data, does it make sense to use RavenDB or should i use Redis for this since Redis is soo much faster than RavenDB? (SQL server is not a choice for the current project).

Comment: Are you planning to write your own message bus based on raven db?

Comment: yes. since there is none yet! :-) the question is: does it make sense or should i just install redis on a server and use redis only for signalr.

Comment: Have you looked at NServiceBus?

Comment: @MattJohnson do you mwan? http://nservicebus.com/ ? i do not see how it would help me.

Comment: Yes.  You can use NServiceBus as a backplane to scale out SignalR.  [Here's a great writeup](http://roycornelissen.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/an-nservicebus-backplane-for-signalr/).  There are plenty of other examples if you google for "NServiceBus SignalR".   Also, NServiceBus uses RavenDB for persistent storage, so if you are already using RavenDB, it's a great fit.

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks. did not find that in my initial google query. looks indeed great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally created one myself.

https://github.com/esskar/SignalR.RavenDB